# can i locate element on UI Automator of an ongoing call?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, appium-android

can I locate an element on UI Automator of an ongoing call?
Steps:
1. I made a call and the other person picks the call.
2. Now I want to locate element present now on the screen and make another call is it possible?

[image]

Snapshot of UI Automator Viewer when i am on Call and try to take screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's possible you can locate the element id during call.

Comment: @AlImran How? UI Automator Viewer gives Error 

when i am on call and my device is connected. Error while obtaining UI hierarchy XML file: com.android.ddmlib.SyncException: Remote object doesn't exist!

Comment: can you try by using appium inspector instead of UIAutomatorViewer

Comment: Also, restart the Appium server.  Then try another screenshot.

Comment: Not able to take Screenshot.when i am on call.